# Why does the eye move a little when i rotate the bone

Tags: modeling, rigging

I can't realy remember how i did it the last time but the eye is clipping through the eyelid when i rotate the bone around the y axis because it moves a little, its not like this on my human robot model
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image: The eye i got problems with]

[image]

[image]
[image]